# help, my 3 year old son will go to the potty when I take him but will not go on his own even though his potty is RIGHT THERE!

Tags: pre-schooler, potty-training, toilet-training

He's 3 years old and has been peeing in the potty since 18 months. However only when I take him... he goes to daycare 5 times a week and the teachers say he stays dry most of the day.. when I have him at home in underwear he constantly pees himself and will not go on his own. What should I do?

Comment: Why not just keep on taking him?

Comment: Does he take himself to the potty at daycare, or are there regular times when the kids are taken there? (My son's daycare has the latter policy -- regular reminders and opportunities are a big advantage for recently trained kids!)

Comment: Lots of good tips here. Just remember, Krystil, that even if he has been using the potty since 18 months, 3 is still young. It's going to be mostly trial and error until one day he just gets it! Our three (almost four) year old has just recently gotten to where he only wets himself occasionally at nights, and he still sometimes asks for help to go potty until we remind him he can do it by himself.

Answer (score 3):

Daycare usually have scheduled bathroom times and will encourage all children to try at those times. This could be why he is not having accidents at daycare. 
I would go back to taking him into the bathroom at regular intervals when he is home with you. He may simply be too involved in his play to be paying attention to his body until it is too late.

Answer (score 1):

One thing my wife and I did when we were at this stage was to set an alarm (on a phone or otherwise) that goes off every hour or so as a cue to go try. It worked pretty well for us, but of course not all children are the same.